# text from url, but it gets copied 3 to 4 times

Tags: java, url, jsoup

when i execute this code, the raw data from the website is getting written, but it gets written like 3-4 times the same content..i am not sure how to resolve this..can anyone help me out..

I use JSoup..

```
public static void main(String a[])
{
    try 
    {
    //URL url=new URL("https://in.yahoo.com/?p=us");
    Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.businessinsider.in/").get();
    Elements contents = doc.select("div") ;


    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("E:/outputtext.txt")); 
    for(Element p : contents) {
        out.print(p.text());
    }
   catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStacktrace();
    }
}
```

content from the website gets saved in that .txt file, but the content gets       copied like 3-4 times in the same file...

Comment: I updated my answer to address your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your selector `doc.select("div")` you pick up all `div` elements of the document, also the ones inside other `div` elements, resulting in some duplication.

Maybe you should differentiate and only select the ones you need.

If you want to get the full content, you do not need the Jsoup parser at all. You still can use Jsoup for the net access, but you can leave out the parser like this:

```
Connection con = Jsoup.connect("http://www.businessinsider.in/");    
Response res = con.execute();
String rawContent = res.body();
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("E:/outputtext.txt"));
out.print(rawContent);
```

Or, if you have use for the parser after all, you could get the `body` tag instead of `div`

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.businessinsider.in/").get();
Element bodyEl = doc.body();
String bodySt = bodyEl.html();
```

Comment: is there any other way to grab all the text content from url without html tags..?